# C# application Deployment with remote server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I developed a small application in C# Winforms with a SQL Server database.
Now I want to deploy it where client is using server with SQL Server installed on it, and he wants to use the `.exe` file on another machine.

I need to make a connection so I added my database files in SQL Server and I changed my connection string to this:

```
public class DatabaseConnection
{
    private static string constring = @"Data Source=192.xxx.x.xxx\MYSRV;Initial Catalog=dbEmployee;User ID=sa;Password=sa$123";
    public static SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(constring);
}
```

but I still can't run my application - I keep getting this:

[image: Error].

Comment: Do you have an instance of SQL Server at that IP named "MYSRV".  Check out http://www.connectionstrings.com/  As a side note its not a good idea to use sa for user connections

Comment: Check the IP address of the SQL Server which hosts your database.

Comment: @bit i verified the ip address there is no problem with that.

Comment: Can you connect to the database using SSMS ?

Comment: yes, i checked the server machine and i used to the database with SSMS.

Comment: Are you able to do all this from the machine on which the client has the .exe ?

Comment: Probably a firewall issue, try searching.